# run ruby-prof with a script that takes arguments

Tags: ruby, rubygems, benchmarking, ruby-prof

I know how to start **ruby-prof** with a script:

```
 ruby-prof -p multi [SCRIPT_PATH]/my_script.rb
```

but how can I run ruby-prof with a script that takes arguments ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most commands that run another command will let you do this with the special double dash `--` option, followed by the arguments you want to pass through. ruby-prof follows this norm.

If you have a Ruby file like this:

```
# test.rb
puts "ARGV: #{ARGV.inspect}"
```

You can run `ruby-prof` like this and get the args:

```
» ruby-prof test.rb -- arg1 arg2
ARGV: ["arg1", "arg2"]
```

So in your specific case, you can do this:

```
» ruby-prof -p multi [SCRIPT_PATH]/my_script.rb -- arg1 arg2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @brainbag  you were right, 
I used the Help of the command `ruby-prof -h` and i get help on how to use gem:   `Usage: ruby-prof [options] <script.rb> [--] [profiled-script-command-line-options]`
So for my example the answer will be:   `ruby-prof -p multi [SCRIPT_PATH]/my_script.rb -- --argument1='A' --argument1='B'`